# Query by comparing pieces within a document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The documents i'm querying on have two sub parts called `OldResults` and `NewResults`. What i want to do is to find all documents where `OldResults != NewResults`. Is such a query possible in Mongo? Please be aware that the schema of `OldResults` & `NewResults` could be different for different documents but within the same document they should be the same.

@chridam here is the exception i get:

```
Error("Printing Stack Trace")@:0
()@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37
([object Array])@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:866
@(shell):10

uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$setEquals'",
    "code" : 15999,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)**, in particular the [**`$setEquals`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setEquals/) operator as it compares two or more arrays and returns true if they have the same distinct elements and false otherwise:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "NewResults": 1,
            "OldResults": 1,
            "AreResultsSame": { "$setEquals": [ "$NewResults", "$OldResults" ] }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": { "AreResultsSame": false }
    }
]);
```

Let's demonstrate this with a couple of test documents:

```
db.collection.insert([
    { 
        _id: 1,
        OldResults: [
            { a: 1, b: 1 },
            { a: 1, b: 2 }
        ],
        NewResults: [
            { a: 1, b: 1 },
            { a: 1, b: 2 }
        ]
    },
    { 
        _id: 2,
        OldResults: [
            { a: 1, b: 1 },
            { a: 1, b: 2 }
        ],
        NewResults: [
            { a: 1, b: 2 },
            { a: 1, b: 2 }
        ]
    }
])
```

So the above aggregation will output the document with `_id: 2` since the 2 arrays are not the same:

**Output**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "OldResults": [ 
                { "a": 1, "b": 1 }, 
                { "a": 1, "b": 2 }
            ],
            "NewResults": [ 
                { "a": 1, "b": 2 }, 
                { "a": 1, "b": 2 }
            ],
            "AreResultsSame": false
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: I get an exception when i try that. I will put the details in the question.

Comment: i think i found the problem. I think '$setequals' was added in version # 2.6. I have version that is in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (which is v2.4.9))